# setInterval JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a project where I use `setInterval`. I have read up on it a little bit, but I can't really understand it. What happens is it works fine, but after around 20 seconds it starts to get faster and faster until it lags out my pc.

```
var autorefresh = setInterval(function () {
    $('#holder').fadeOut('slow').load('index.php').fadeIn('slow');
}, 5000);
```

As I said this works fine, until it starts getting gradually faster and faster.

Comment: You do know that `load` is not put on the `fx` queue, but executed immediately?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know what you're trying to do, but what this code will do is increase the number of concurrently running functions until, as you say, it becomes unmanageable. If a request takes more than 5 seconds (which is possible if you have many pages fetching creating high load) then you will have more than one load in progress at any time.

EDIT: The asker would like to "refresh a div every 5 seconds".

The reason this isn't working is because refreshing is not instantaneous, it takes time. But the loop does not respect that and refreshes ever 5 seconds no matter how long the load takes. This means that at any point the network may respond with one of the ajax requests and `fadeIn`, and you may get two `fadeIn`s running at once.

To fix this, we wait until the ajax `load` and the `fadeIn` has completed before setting a `timeOut` for another request.

```
var refresh = function() {
    $('#holder').fadeOut('slow').load('index.php').fadeIn("slow",
        function(){setTimeout(refresh,5000)});
}
refresh();
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Could you give us some context as to what you want to accomplish with this piece of code first?

Comment: I am using this to refresh a div every 5 seconds, i removed the fadein and fadeout, same problem

Comment: Hi @user1926053 if this answers your question you can mark it as correct by clicking the 'tick'.